# Usecase for Generic Classes in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

What's the difference between a `generic` class and `vertex` or `edge` classes?  Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB is a multi-model database.
Data modeling is introduced inside the documentation:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Document-and-graph-model.html

At the base, there's the document model, with inheritance. Vertex and Edge (V, E) are specialized subclasses used by the graph model.
In the same way, the user can define his hierarchy of classes (in the OrientDB jargon, the class is a table).

A concrete example. 
Define a class Person as a vertex, then two subclasses Employee and Customer. So Employee and Customer are Person and are Vertex too.

A good example here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Using-schema-with-graphs.html

I hope this can help